# The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'OpenCvSharp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, winforms, opencv

I am new to C# and Winforms.  I am following a tutorial to use OpenCVSharp4 (it says version 3 is now deprecated).  But I get this error.

[image: Error In Code]

I have added both OpenCvSharp4 and OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win in Nuget.  When I view the code in Github, I can find the namespace there in version 4 of OpenCvSharp.  E.g. https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/master/src/OpenCvSharp.Extensions/BitmapConverter.cs

Comment: Have you tried "the usual" - clean the solution, delete bin/obj folders, restart the VS?

Comment: It looks like you need either OpenCVSharp4 and OpenCVSharp4.Extensions or else OpenCVSharp4.Windows.

Comment: I found the solution, there is a separate nuget package called OpenCvSharp4.Exentions, sorry I did not notice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from PM console:
NuGet\Install-Package OpenCvSharp4.Extensions -Version 4.6.0.20220608

or

dotnet add package OpenCvSharp4.Extensions --version 4.6.0.20220608

Comment: Yes I forgot this, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I googled, you should install this:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4.Extensions

Answer (score 1):

It's 100% normal.

"Using" is for you don't have to specify the origin of the resource each time.
For example instead of writing "**System.Windows.Forms.Button**" you can just write "**Button**".

In your case, "**using OpenCvSharp**;" is OK. But, "**OpenCvSharp.Extensions**" doesn't exist.

In the GitHub sample, you have "namespace OpenCvSharp.Extensions".
So "OpenCvSharp.Extensions" is the **namespace**, not a shortcut like "OpenCvSharp". This is how the programmer named his program, not a ressource to be used :

[image: github sample]

Otherwise there would be "**using** OpenCvSharp.Extensions", not "**namespace** OpenCvSharp.Extensions".

This is the sample in the main page : https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp

[image: usage sample]

Comment: `OpenCvSharp` is also namespace.

Comment: You are right, it was for differentiation purpose. Should I try to specify it ?

Comment: TBH I don't understand what you are trying to explain. OP issue was missing nuget package (it seems that there were some breaking changes, including breaking library into multiple packages) after installing which everything started compiling again.

Comment: He takes as an example the code of the link he put in his question. The only place where OpenCvSharp.Extensions appears is in the namespace declaration. So I think he confused the namespace with the "using". The sample in the github main page doesn't mention "OpenCvSharp.Extensions".

Comment: OP takes some tutorial which uses `using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;` which fails to compile with OpenCvSharp 4 nuget and goes to the source code to find that the namespace still exists.